# Avoid Chrome to check for internet connection (PHP/Chrome/ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: php, google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04

I have a slideshow that cache all files in the browser. If i unplug the internet cable, it will run the slideshow from cache. And it will detect internet if I plug the internet cable back in.

But, if I start the browser without internet available, it will not start. I then get "This site cant be reached" as error message in chrome. When I plug the internet cable back in, it will start automatically after few minutes.

How can I avoid Chrome (version 49) to check for internet connection and rather use the cached files?